# How to check browser compatibility/support for image and video?

Tags: c#, reactjs

I'm just trying to check browser compatibility with images and videos in the Reactjs website application. If the extension of the image/video does not support, then it has to show a alert message or an action. how to do this ?

Tried Modernizr

Comment: `Tried Modernizr` And did it work? Have you read https://davidwalsh.name/detect-supported-video-formats-javascript ?

Comment: What types of images and video do you need to support?

Answer (score 0):

I tried, the given code is working for me :

```
videoBrowserSupportValidation() {
    const extension = filename.split('.').pop(); // This is to get extenstion of your video file and filename is video file name
    const vidpath1 = "video/";
    var obj = document.createElement('video');
    var videoType = obj.canPlayType(vidpath1+extension); 
    if (videoType == "") {
        console.log("Invalid file , browser does not recognize video formats ");          
        // write your action
    }
    else {
        console.log("Valid file");  
        // write your action
    }
```

Comment: This is only for video